# git command to diff the nth modified file of a git status output

Tags: git, bash

I often run a `git status` and then want to see the specific diffs of one of those files.  So after:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:  path/to/modified/file1
    modified:  path/to/modified/file1
```

Is it possible with git, or as a fallback bash, to `git diff` the nth modified file, so that `git diff <someMagic(2)>` would reduce to `git diff path/to/modified/file2`.

my main question is if this exists within git, and if not to help with a bash command.

Comment: Not within Git, but easy enough to construct using `git status --porcelain` and `tail +$1 | head -1` or `sed -n -e '$1{p;q;}'`.

Answer (score 1):

If automation is not your goal, then I would say that `git add -i` would fit your case.

Have a look at [git add -i](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) documentation.

If you're looking for a script then I've done something that does exactly what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff $(git status | grep modified | sed 's/^.*:   //' | head -n "$1" | tail -n 1)
```

The way to use it is to call it and then pass the number of the modified file you want to diff: `<script_name> N`, where **N** is number of the "nth modified file".

(e.g. using your example, if I call `<script>.sh 2` it would call diff like this: `git diff path/to/modified/file2`)

Comment: hmm, i want to diff files before i even think about staging things.  i just find copying the changed files paths to `git diff ...` to be tedious.

Comment: assuming the output structure of git status is known, one (not me) could presumably craft a sed command that picks the nth modified line and splices out the `modified:` bit ;)

Comment: @AlexBollbach I've edited my answer to match your intent. I believe it solves your problem, can you check and tell me if it suits you?